# TikZpicture/pgfplots: How to insert time-data in mm:ss-format (without hh:) into x-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

**Imagine an ordinary x/y-diagram by using the `pgfplots`/`tikzpicture`-packages:**

In case of regular date-values (dd-mm-yyyy) usually there is no problem in application. But now, I have to add times-values in the format of mm:ss (minute:second) without hours (hh:) into the x-axis. How can I solve that?

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   date coordinates in = x,                     % set X-axis as date-axis
    xmin = 0,                                    % minimum-value of X
    xmax = 60,                                   % maximum value of X
    ymin = 0,                                    % minimum-value of Y
    ymax = 2200,                                 % maximum-value of Y
    xlabel={time [min]},                         % caption of X-axis
    ylabel = {pressure [mm H2O]},                % caption of Y-axis
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \addplot plot coordinates {(0,0)(60,2000)};  % just to show some line
%   \addplot table[x=time,y=pressure]{data.txt}; % the "real" data
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**For example, the belonging data-table `data.txt` looks like that:**

```
time    pressure
00:00   -3
00:01   50
00:01   170
01:02   300
02:02   500
03:03   700
04:03   750
05:04   800
10:04   1100
01:05   1200
18:05   1300
19:06   1400
20:06   1500
00:07   1600
30:07   1700
40:08   1800
50:08   1900
55:09   2000
59:09   2000
60:00   2000
```

---

How can I add such a time-format inside diagram's x-axis)? Setting `date coordinates in = x` didn't bring the solution for me - maybe seconds are not accepted as a date...

---

**Edit: Maybe this could be an approach?**

```
\begin{filecontents}{mydata.csv}
X   Y1
 00:00.0   25
 00:00.5   25
 00:01.0   25.2
 00:01.5   25.7
 00:02.0   26.7
 00:02.5   27.7
 00:03.0   28.7
 00:03.5   29.7
 00:04.0   30.6
 00:04.5   31.6
 00:05.0   32.6
 00:05.5   33.6
 00:06.0   34.4
 00:06.5   35.4
 00:07.0   36.3
 00:07.5   37.2
 00:08.0   38.1
 00:08.5   38.9
 00:09.0   39.7
 00:09.5   40.5
 00:10.0   41.3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mylabel.csv}
X
 00:00.0
 00:01.0
 00:02.0
 00:03.0
 00:04.0
 00:05.0
 00:06.0
 00:07.0
 00:08.0
 00:09.0
 00:10.0
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[paper=a4,parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
       \centering
       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[width=0.6\textheight,      
       height=0.4\textheight,
       xlabel={Time [mm:ss.0]},
       ylabel={Temperature [Celsius]},
       ymajorgrids,
       xtick={0,2,...,100},
       xticklabels from table={mylabel.csv}{X},,
       xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
       legend pos=outer north east,
       legend cell align=left,
       legend style={draw=none}]
       \addplot[color=black,mark=none] table [x expr=\coordindex,y=Y1] {mydata.csv};
       \legend{Graph}
       \end{axis}
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image]

---

Unfortunately, I get different errors when changing the mm:ss:0-format into my desired mm:ss-format...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this solution is working fine indeed:

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\begin{filecontents}{mydata.csv}
X   Y1
 00:00.0   25
 00:00.5   25
 00:01.0   25.2
 00:01.5   25.7
 00:02.0   26.7
 00:02.5   27.7
 00:03.0   28.7
 00:03.5   29.7
 00:04.0   30.6
 00:04.5   31.6
 00:05.0   32.6
 00:05.5   33.6
 00:06.0   34.4
 00:06.5   35.4
 00:07.0   36.3
 00:07.5   37.2
 00:08.0   38.1
 00:08.5   38.9
 00:09.0   39.7
 00:09.5   40.5
 00:10.0   41.3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mylabel.csv}
X
 00:00.0
 00:01.0
 00:02.0
 00:03.0
 00:04.0
 00:05.0
 00:06.0
 00:07.0
 00:08.0
 00:09.0
 00:10.0
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[paper=a4,parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
       \centering
       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[width=0.6\textheight,      
       height=0.4\textheight,
       xlabel={Time [mm:ss.0]},
       ylabel={Temperature [Celsius]},
       ymajorgrids,
       xtick={0,2,...,100},
       xticklabels from table={mylabel.csv}{X},,
       xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
       legend pos=outer north east,
       legend cell align=left,
       legend style={draw=none}]
       \addplot[color=black,mark=none] table [x expr=\coordindex,y=Y1] {mydata.csv};
       \legend{Graph}
       \end{axis}
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

It didn't work yesterday, because I didn't know that I have to delete the generated `mydata.csv` manually before starting a new compilation... So if you're changing the indicated values inside your TeX-GUI, they won't be changed inside the generated mydata.csv automatically during compilation...

Comment: The values in `mydata.csv` will only be changed if you include `\usepackage{filecontents}` in your preamble. Without that package, the `filecontents` environment only creates new files, but doesn't replace existing ones.

Comment: How can I use your code if I have a large csv file? I mean without using the "filecontents"